# Apple Sandbox: Only receive 'INITIAL_BUY' server notifications

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

We have setup Apple’s Server notifications for auto-renewable subscriptions. Last month we still able to get all notification type(*INITIAL_BUY, RENEWAL, INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL*).

Recently when we tested with sandbox (1 year subscription), we receive only 'INITIAL_BUY' server notifications, we were expect to receive 'RENEWAL' server notifications after 1 hour, but we are not getting those notifications.

**Question:**

I just want to confirm that is it a new notifications service that only send us 'INITIAL_BUY' notifications? And there are no server-to server notification if the renewal is successful?

**Note**:**

We did validate receipt with verifyReceipt server to check latest_receipt_info.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. According to this technical note (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-SUBSCRIPTIONS-MY_SERVER_PROCESS_RARELY_RECEIVES_RENEWAL_NOTICES_WHEN_THE_AUTO_RENEWING_SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWS_)

> The App Store attempts to charge the user account 24 hours before an auto-renewing subscription expires. If the renewal is successful, there is no server-to server notification because the auto-renewing subscription did not enter into the expired state.

You have to actively call Apple's receipt validation endpoint on or around the expiration date of each receipt (and possible for a few days after that) to fetch the renewal receipts. Apple will not notify your servers.

Comment: `we were expect to receive 'RENEWAL'` - Renewal notifications are triggered when a user's subscription had expired for some reason not opted by user(other than canceling through settings or calling customer care e.g billing failure etc) and is later renewed when the problem is fixed (adding a new card etc). Apple retries billing for 60 days post expiration.